# How do I change the values in the array of struct in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I haven't understood(I don't know) how to update the colour "yellow" to "blue" and its id to 5. Solving the example would help me to understand. Thanks

```
--create or replace table mydataset.struct_4 (boxes string,colors array<struct<colour string,id int64>>)
--insert into mydataset.struct_4 (boxes,colors) values("box_1",[("brown",1),("green",3),("white",7)]),("box_2",[("yellow",2),("white",4)])
select * from `mydataset.struct_4`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  boxes, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      IF(colour = 'yellow', 'blue', colour) colour, 
      IF(colour = 'yellow', 5, id) id
    FROM UNNEST(colors)
  ) colors
FROM `mydataset.struct_4`
```

Variation of above would be

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  boxes, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT IF(colour = 'yellow', 
      STRUCT<colour STRING,id INT64>('blue', 5), 
      STRUCT(colour, id)) 
    FROM UNNEST(colors)
  ) colors
FROM `mydataset.struct_4`
```

with the same output of course

```sql
Row boxes   colors.colour   colors.id    
1   box_1   brown           1    
            green           3    
            white           7    
2   box_2   blue            5    
            white           4
```

> Update for: but how do I update the colour "yellow" to "blue" and its id to 5 using UPDATE DML statement :)

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `mydataset.struct_4` SET colors = ARRAY(
    SELECT IF(colour = 'yellow', 
        STRUCT<colour STRING,id INT64>('blue', 5), 
        STRUCT(colour, id)) 
    FROM UNNEST(colors)
) WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: but how do I update the colour "yellow" to "blue" and its id to 5  using UPDATE DML statement :)

Comment: sorry, I thought it is obvious with initial answer. See update in my answer :o)